# AutoClearedValue accessed from another thread after View is Destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I am using AutoClearedValue class from [this link](https://itnext.io/an-update-to-the-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-the-bug-weve-inherited-from-autoclearedvalue-7fc0a89fcae1) and  when view is destroyed, backing field becomes null and that is good but i have a thread(actually a kotlin coroutine) that after it is done, it accesses the value(which uses autoCleared) but if before it's Job is done i navigate to another fragment(view of this fragment is destroyed), then it tries to access the value, but since it is null i get an exception and therefore a crash.
what can i do about this?

also for which variables this autoCleared needs to be used? i use it for viewBinding and recyclerview adapters.

Comment: Can't you put null check before access ?

Comment: nullable field is in autoClearedValue, so i do not have access to it. i can put everything in try/catch but that is something that can be forgot and cause problems

Comment: @mohsensameti you should call coroutine in lifecycle aware fashion. So the update only happens when the view is at least started. for eg., if you're calling a web service then you should overserve the response and when the response comes live data won't notify your fragment because it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option:

**1-** Cancelling all the running job(s) that may access to view after its destruction. override `onDestroyView()` to do it.

Also, you can launch the coroutines `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` to canceling  it self when view destroy.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    // do sth with view    
}
```

**2- (Preferred solution)** Use Lifecycle aware components (e.g LiveData) between coroutines and view:

coroutines push the state or data in the live-data and you must observe it with [viewLifeCycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner()) scope to update the view.

```
private val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    stateLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { value ->
        binding.textView.text = value
    }
}

private fun fetchSomething() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(10_000)
        stateLiveData.value = "Hello"
    }
}
```